# java program convert numbers to string

Tags: java

How would I create a return for the input of a digit between 100 and 999.

```
 public class numbers {
        static String[] ones={" ","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten",
            "eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","seventeen","eighteen","nineteen"};
        static String [] tens={" ","twenty","thirty","fourty","fifty","sixty","seventy","eighty","ninety"};
        static String [] hundreds={" ","one-hundred","two-hundred","three-hundred","four-hundred",
            "fife-hundred","six-hundred","sevent-hundred","eight-hundred","nine-hundred"};
         static String[] thousand= {"Thousand"};

    public static String UpTONineteen(int i){
        Scanner t=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("please enter a number\n");
        i=t.nextInt();
         while(i>0 && i<20){
             return ones[i];
         }
         while(i>=20 && i<100){
             return tens[i/10]+ones[i%10];
         }while(i>=100 && i<1000){

         }

        return "";

    }

    public static void main(String []args){ 
        numbers b=new numbers();
        System.out.print(b.UpTONineteen(10));

    }

    }
```

Comment: why do you ose while() { return } instead of if () { return } ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the following code should work:

```
return hundreds[i / 100] + tens[(i % 100) / 10] + ones[i % 10];
```

Comment: thanks alot man. so in relation to your answer getting a return over 1000 would be thousand[1/1000]+hundres[i % 100) / 10]+hundres[i%10]+ones[i%10]?

Comment: Not exactly - it must be: return thousand[i / 1000] + hundreds[(i % 1000) / 100] + tens[(i % 100) / 10] + ones[i % 10];

Comment: }while(i>=1000&&i<20000){
   return ones[i/1000]+" "+thousand[i/i]+" "+ hundreds[i%1000/100]+tens[i%10]+ ones[i%10];
  }while(i>=20000){
   return tens[i/10000]+" "+thousand[i/i]+" "+ hundreds[i%1000/100]+tens[i%10]+ ones[i%10];

Comment: thanks i ticked your solution as the answer twice...i'm not sure why it appears unticked on my end but thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

First :you have a problem with tens array , it need to be like this because you use the index

```
static String[] tens = {" ", " ", "twenty", "thirty", "fourty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"};
```

second :the hundred range

```
return hundreds[i / 100] +" "+ tens[(i % 100) / 10] +" "+ ones[i % 10];
```

Comment: yes, i allready knew about that, i had a problem with the maths and mod stuff. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while(i>=100 && i<1000){
    return hundreds[i / 100] + tens[Math.max((i % 100) / 10-1,0)] + ones[i % 10];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

String.valueOf() is your friend. search how to use it ;)

 [examples](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_valueof.htm)